# Meaning of "due" in "when my second child was due"

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context

What does due mean in *when my second child was due*?

I would interpret it in three ways:

1. just born.
2. about to be born soon.
3. just got pregnant.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*When my child is due* refers to the time the baby is expected to be born.

Comment: Unless, of course, your first child (by the same wife) had not been born yet. Then all bets are off.

Comment: A common phrase would be something along the lines of "I'm due in February!" to inform the listener(s) that the baby is expected to be born in February.

Answer (score 5):

It means "about to born."

One of the meaning of *due* is "under engagement as to time; expected to be ready, be present, or arrive; scheduled."